# Rust code implementing cosine similarity

Tags: performance, rust, clustering, natural-language-processing

I've been trying to create a piece of code which consists of looping through each element of a list of questions, preprocess it, and then calculate the Cosine similarity with the rest of the elements (questions) not including the same element. At the end of each iteration of the main_question, the code will then add the index of the main_question as a key and the value will be a list of index of each question which had a cosine greater than 0.6 in a HashMap or a dictionary.

With release mode the execution time is 31 seconds for each iteration. so with over 66k iteration,  can't image how much time I'll take to complete.

What I want is to make the code much faster, I'd be hoping if you could help me optimize the code by suggesting me whether to implement separate function handling certain things differently, make use of faster organized extern packages or other ways...

Here's the code, and it works fine and outputs the desired results.
And here's the Github repo providing everything you need to run the program:

[https://github.com/IhabMks/Rust-Cosine-similarity.git](https://github.com/IhabMks/Rust-Cosine-similarity/tree/1f64987da5329af385c29ca4c106073b924f7149)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
mod stopwords;
mod questions;
extern crate time;
use time::PreciseTime;
fn main() {
    let mut my_hash = HashMap::new();
    let stop_word: Vec<String> = stopwords::stop_word(); // function to load up a vector of stop_words
    let questions: Vec<String> = questions::questions(); // function to load up a vector of the questions
    
    for (index, main_question) in questions.iter().enumerate() {
        let start = PreciseTime::now();
        let mut similarities: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
        let mut b: Vec<String> = questions.to_vec();
        let x_vec: Vec<String> = main_question.split(" ").map(|v| String::from(v)).collect(); // basic method of tokenizer based on split_whitespace()

        b.remove(index);
        let mut count: u32= 1;

        for _question in b {
            let mut _l1: Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
            let mut _l2: Vec<u16> = Vec::new();
            let  y_vec: Vec<String> = _question.split(" ").map(|v| String::from(v)).collect();
            

            if x_vec.len() == 0 || y_vec.len() == 0 {
                continue;
            }
            let mut x_set: Vec<&str> = vec![];
            let mut y_set: Vec<&str> = vec![];
            for word in &x_vec {
                if !stop_word.contains(&word) {
                    x_set.push(&word);
                }
            }
            for word in &y_vec {
                if !stop_word.contains(&word) {
                    y_set.push(&word);
                }
            }
            //let mut rvector: Vec<&str> = [x_set, y_set].concat();
            let mut rvector: Vec<&str> = x_set.iter().copied().chain(y_set.iter().copied()).collect();
            rvector.sort();
            rvector.dedup();
            
            for word in &rvector {
                if x_set.contains(&word) {
                    _l1.push(1);
                } else {_l1.push(0)}
                if y_set.contains(&word) {
                    _l2.push(1);
                } else {_l2.push(0)}
            }
            
            let mut c: u16 = 0;
            for i in 0..(rvector.len()){
                c+= _l1[i]*_l2[i];
            }
            
            let cosine: f32 = (c as f32) / f32::powf((_l1.iter().sum::<u16>() * _l2.iter().sum::<u16>()) as f32, 0.5);
            if cosine > 0.6{
                similarities.push(questions.iter().position(|r| r == &_question).unwrap() as i32);
            }
            println!("Index: {} -> iter nb: {}",index, count);
            count+=1;
        }
        let end = PreciseTime::now();
        println!("Index: {} lasted {} seconds.", index, start.to(end));
        my_hash.insert(index, similarities);
    }
    println!("hash {:?}",my_hash);
}
```

Comment: I don't think `stopwords` and `questions` are standard crates, and they are not given as part of your code, which means we can't run your code without them. Could you make a small Github repo with everything needed to run your code and post the link here, so that people can actually test any suggestions?

Comment: Just a quick observation - you do this `_question.split(" ").map(|v| String::from(v)).collect()` in both your loops, and this seems to be something which can be pre-computed once and then cached for use in the loops. Should save a bunch of time! Try it and report back.

Comment: You can also see if you can turn `stop_word` into a set, they offer `O(1)` inclusion checks, which can become significant over long-running loops.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I've edited the post including the GitHub repo so you can run it. I  will also try what you suggested up above and thanks.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I've implemented a HashSet instead of vector and it is indeed way faster, I was amazed that each iteration takes about 1.5sec now, which is a long way since I started testing. And speaking about the splitting part, can you elaborate how to achieve it?

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I haven't changed the code in the question as it still uses vector as you can see. I can share the updated version of the code that uses HashSet now if you want to.

Comment: Oh never mind then, I misread the stuff with the HashMap

Comment: Also I had to install Rust just for this question, so that's why it's taking me a while.

Comment: I put in a pull request to your GitHub repo, https://github.com/IhabMks/Rust-Cosine-similarity/pull/1 . Try it out and let me know how it goes on your system. When I ran it on my Ryzen 7 4800H laptop it ran through everything (all 66,018 iterations of the outer loop) in under 3 minutes (171-178 seconds), using around 130MB or less RAM.

Comment: If it's all good I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury Just checked the repo, check the conversation.